# How to know if user finished selecting text inside PDFView

Tags: ios, swift, macos, pdfkit, mac-catalyst

There is a problem that `macCatalyst` in not support mouse events as it does `AppKit` with not ported (maccatalyst) `macOS` apps.
I need to know when user finished selecting some portion of text inside PDF file with `PDFKit` using mouse or track pad.
Maybe somebody has solution or can suggest an idea how to implement somethings like `mouseUp` or `touchedEnded` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your own GestureRecocongiser:

```
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class TouchUpGestureRecogniser: UIGestureRecognizer {
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        state = UIGestureRecognizerState(rawValue: 3)!
    }
    
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        state = UIGestureRecognizerState(rawValue: 4)!
    }
    
}
```

Then inside your VC, where PDFView is located:

```
let customGesture = TouchUpGestureRecogniser(target: self, action: #selector(touchUp(_:)))
customGesture.delegate = self
pdfView.addGestureRecognizer(customGesture)
```

and finally:

```
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**NOTE: If you have more than 1 gesture on PDFView please test them, if there will be any issues merge them using UIGestureRecognizerDelegate functions.**